# Bar Charts height in PHP

Tags: php

So I guess this is more a math question than PHP but I don't know where else it would go. So I have a tv show website which shows ratings distribution from every users. Two examples can be seen here http://broadcasted.tv/user/2/albertmarch/ and here http://broadcasted.tv/user/21/freshprincelive/. 
Here is the formula I use to calculate each of the bars at the moment:

```
$division = $scores[$i][1]  / $countvotestotal; 
//we divide the number of scores for each score (1 to 10) by the total number of score
$percentage = $division * 100;
$pixels = 180;
//max number of pixels
$pixelsactual = ($percentage / 100) * $pixels;
$addthat = $percentage * 3.4;
//add some pixels to give more relief to the charts (otherwise, with many ratings, you end having bars between 10px and 20px)
$finalpixels = $pixelsactual + $addthat;
if ($finalpixels > 130) {
    $finalpixels = 130;
}
//and this is a fix that I use, basically, if there is only one rating the biggest bar is gonna be huge (especially because of the $addthat var which add some px with a ratio to the final pixels value)
```

The issue is that some charts look shit (like on the first profile) or that different values have the same bar size like there http://broadcasted.tv/user/98/armchairtv/

Any recommendation would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts I recently discovered http://www.highcharts.com/demo/

I really enjoyed it because it dealt with all the aesthetics

It will also provide lots of different chart types for you. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic

Comment: I checked that out and it's good, customizing it to make it look like my current charts looks like it'll be a huge pain in the ass. But their bar height is good so I'm gonna try to figure out how they get it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should optimize your code replacing

```
$pixelsactual = ($percentage / 100) * $pixels;
```

by

```
$pixelsactual = $division * $pixels;
```

`$percentage` variable isn't really needed here.

The problem is that you're hacking so that all bars get visible. Then it's expectable that some charts will have multiple bars with different values at the same height.

I would recommend you to remove that hack (and the 130px hack, you should just put it in $pixels), and use a function with a decreasing derived function (like log or something like that), so that small values would gain height fastly, when higher values would gain height more slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
First get the highest data from your data array.

```
$highest=max($array);
```

Then get 1% of it.

```
$x=$highest*0.01; // 1%
```

now you can do this

```
//$highest*$x=100% or 100px
```

in a loop

```
echo $array[$a]*$x;
```

and you get your variable chart height. 
Tip... You can multiply it *4 for a better px height